# Paths in the city

Tags: logic

The figure below represents four linked routes as $ A $ and $ B $ cities.
Review a picture and indicate a correct alternative:
[image]

a) The path is shorter II

b) Path II is less than III

c) Path III is shorter than IV

d) Path II is shorter than IV

e) Paths I, II, III and IV are of equal length.

Solution: [image]

All paths have lengths equal to the sum $ (a + b)$ of the following rectangle triangle collars:
This solution does not make much sense to me. He has not proved anything!

Comment: Are the lines painted on a grid?

Comment: @Bman72 I dont know! The '' solution '' is just this

Comment: Because if they were on a grid you could say that to go from A to B, you'd have to go $n$ times left and $m$ times right. Doesn't matter which way you choose. But the picture is kind of misleading in my opinion

Comment: If you look at the cross in the Swiss flag (or the Red Cross flag, doesn't matter which), do you know why its circumference is the same as that of a square with the same width and height? If you look at that until it clicks, this problem will follow shortly thereafter.

Comment: @Arthur Please explain to me what you just said? I don't understand how I can relate this to the problem ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is why first route equals to $(a+b)$, and similar for the rest:
[image]

Comment: Can you explain your drawing a little?

Comment: @JeffersonNascimento try to move each length on the blue route to the line segment $a$, also move each length on the orange  route to the line segement $b$, you will find they have the same length

Answer (score 1):

Hint: consider path I; at the second corner, imagine to draw a rectangle with the sides next to the second corner. What can you see?